# Filter rows based on ID over multiple data frames with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

How can I filter 180 .csv files from my global directory based on a matching ID in another df named 'Camera' in R? When I tried to incorporate my one by one file filtering code (see step 3b) into a for-loop (see step 3a) I get the error:

> **Error in paste("i")$SegmentID : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**.

I'm quite new to for loop functions, so I really appreciate your help! All the 180 files have a unique name, are different in length, but have the same column structure & names. They look like:

```
 df 'File1'             df 'Camera'
 ID  Speed  Location      ID  Time  
 1   30    4              1   10
 2   35    5              3   11
 3   40    6              5   12
 4   30    7
 5   35    8

 Filtered df 'File1'            
 ID  Speed  Location 
 1   30    4
 3   40    6
 5   35    8
```

These are some samples of my code:

```
#STEP 1: read files
filenames <- list.files(path="06-06-2017_0900-1200uur",
                        pattern="*.csv")

# STEP 2: import files
for(i in filenames){
  filepath <- file.path("06-06-2017_0900-1200uur",paste(i))
  assign(i, read.csv2(filepath, header = TRUE, skip = "1"))
}

# STEP 3a: delete rows that do not match ID in df 'Cameras'
for(i in filesnames){
    paste("i") <- paste("i")[paste("i")$ID %in% Cameras$ID,]
}

#STEP 3b: filtering one by one
    File1  <- File1[File1$ID   %in% Camera$ID,]
```

Comment: Why is one loop `for(i in filenames)` and the other `for(i in names)`?

Comment: Also, I think using `assign()` and assigning variables with long complicated names is a bad way to go. Create a list and assign the csvs to the list.

Comment: In step 3, here does the "names" object come from?
What are you trying to do with paste("i") <- ...?
 i is a placeholder for a number within a sequence, and objects can not begin with numbers. They must begin with letters. Now, if you want to call your object i (a very bad idea within your loop), you can disregard the paste() and the dblquotes.

Comment: @Marius, was a typo! Corrected it, thanks for you other comment as well. Do you have an idea as well how I could filter the .csv files based on a matching ID in another df?

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez, I thought in that way I could call the .csv files one by one that I have stored in 'filenames'. I tried to incorporate this code into the for loop: File1[File1$ID   %in% Camera$ID,]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that makes use of lists (generally a better way to go).  First, utilize the `include.names` argument in `list.files()`:

```
fns <- list.files(
  path = "06-06-2017_0900-1200uur",
  pattern = "*.csv",
  include.names = T
  )
```

Now you have a list of your filenames.  Next, apply `read.csv2` to each of the filenames in your list:

```
dat <- lapply(fns, read.csv2, header = T, skip = 1)
```

Now you have a list of data frames (the output from calling `read.csv`).  Finally, apply `subset()` to each of the data frames to keep only those rows which match the ID column:

```
out <- lapply(dat, function(x) subset(x, ID %in% Camera$ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, the output should be a data frame from file1 where the ID for all rows matches one of the rows in the Camera file.

This is easily accomplished with the `sqldf()` package and structured query language.

```
rawFile1 <- "ID  Speed  Location
1   30    4  
2   35    5  
3   40    6  
4   30    7  
5   35    8  
"

rawCamera <- "      ID  Time  
1   10    
3   11    
5   12    
"
file1 <- read.table(textConnection(rawFile1),header=TRUE)
Camera <- read.table(textConnection(rawCamera),header=TRUE)

library(sqldf)
sqlStmt <- "select * from file1 where ID in(select ID from Camera)"
sqldf(sqlStmt,drv="SQLite")
```

...and the output:

```
  ID Speed Location
1  1    30        4
2  3    40        6
3  5    35        8
>
```

To extend this logic to a number of csv files, first we obtain the list of files from the subdirectory where they are stored using the `list.files()` function. For example, if the files were in a `data` subdirectory of the R working directory, one might use the following function call.

```
theFiles <- list.files("./data/",".csv",full.names=TRUE)
```

We can read these files with `read.table()` to create a `list()` of data frames.

```
theData <- lapply(theFiles,function(x) { 
                      read.table(x,header=TRUE)})
```

To combine the files into a single data frame, we execute `do.call()`.

```
combinedData <- do.call(rbind,theData)
```

Now we can read the camera data and use `sqldf` to keep only the IDs matching the camera data.

```
Camera <- read.table(...,header=TRUE)
library(sqldf)
sqlStmt <- "select * from combinedData where ID in(select ID from Camera)"
sqldf(sqlStmt,drv="SQLite")
```